# "npm run watch" not working and returning error's saying 'missing "Watch"'

Tags: laravel, npm

In my fresh laravel project after adding a tailwind template, I tried running `npm run watch` but it's not working, thus the template is not loading correctly either.

```
$ npm run watch                                                       
npm ERR! Missing script: "watch"                                                                
npm ERR!                                                                                        
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:                                                         
npm ERR!   npm run                                                                              
                                                                                                
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                            
npm ERR!     C:\Users\U-S-E-R\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-27T18_05_36_192Z-debug-0.log
```

[image: Here is the Error Screenshot]

Comment: New Laravel projects do not have `watch` script. You can check available scripts in `package.json` file

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Update your package.json file.

```
...
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "watch": "vite build --watch"
},
...
```

ref: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#rebuild-on-files-changes
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/equivalent-of-vite-watch?reply=809106

Now try running

```
npm run dev
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any script configured in `package.json` file for the watch command?

For Example, An angular application has added it out of the box like following:

```
......
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prod": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  }
......
```

If you didn't have configured it in `package.json` file then you will get the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As someone says, new laravel projects do not have a watch script, now have **vite** instead of **webpack**, so you need to run **npm run dev** instead to let **vite** compile your files.

I dont know if its a kind of bug, but i have notice that when you install some dependency like **npm instal laravel/ui** (**tailwind** in your case), npm adds the **webpack.mix.js** file to the project (even when **vite** is already configured), so, i suggest you to follow this official tutorial to [migrate from vite to webpack](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix) if you want to keep working with **webpack** as always has been, or search how to integrate dependencies to your project with **vite** to keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 9, try npm run build, your changes will be reflected

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but the solution is very simple just follow my steps and your project will start watching your js files

**step 1** : Update your APP_URL
from **APP_URL=http://localhost** to **APP_URL=http://localhost:8000**

**step 2** : start your laravel server
**php artisan serve**

**step 3** : start npm for watching
**npm run dev**

this will start watching your js file for updates and reflect the ui as soon as you save your js files and your application will run on same old url **http://localhost:8000**

**i hope this will help**
feel free to ask any thing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).